# Upload entire folder to Amazon S3 bucket using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need to upload an entire folder of files and subfolders to an Amazon S3 bucket using PHP, does anyone know of a solution to quickly and easily accomplish this? Other libraries I've looked into appear to only support uploading individual files.

Comment: Maybe this stack question will help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667478/how-do-i-bulk-upload-to-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in amazon s3 folder is barely what you give an url name. virtually it creates folder based on url and why you want to use php whereas you can cli. you can upload multiple files that way i.e for each file you can fire a cli command i.e

> s3cmd put source/source1.txt target/target1.txt

Comment: I need to move entire folders of files up to S3 from a PHP app I've built

Comment: you can run system php command into php loop i.e. foreach($files as $file){ system(    s3cmd put source/$file target/target1.txt) }

Answer (score 0):

s3cmd is fabulous solution !!! but instead using php for uploading of directory use **parameter** with **s3cmd** like this: **`s3cmd put --recursive directory_name s3://bucket_name`** in terminal shell....enjoy s3cmd!!

**Note:** Use this [s3cmd link](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) for installation on your platform, for ubuntu lovers just type

- sudo(for non-root) apt-get install s3cmd
- s3cmd --configure (it prompts for your amazon access and secret key)
- then, s3cmd ls (list all buckets)