# uploading to aws s3 via scp or sftp from local linux env

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can you upload to AWS S3 via SCP or SFTP? I can't install s3 utilities on my linux env so i wanted to know if there was another way to do this?

Right, I download the file from my linux env to my laptop and then upload via the web browser...not very efficient...

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such option for SCP, SFTP or even FTP transfers to Amazon S3 ([see this Stack overflow post for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7328863/5269040)).

If you are able to install software on your linux machine, you could use [s3fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount your S3 bucket as a filesystem and then just copy the files to that mounted filesystem.

If you aren't able to install additional software on your linux machine at all, you could also launch an Amazon EC2 instance, e.g. a t2.micro instance eligible for the free-tier usage, and transfer your files to S3 via the EC2 instance.

Comment: On the t2.micro you suggested, you can install proftpd and s3fs and, when properly configured, you have an sftp/ftp-to-S3 gateway, essentially establishing the capability of sending files to S3 using a client that only understands (s)ftp: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23946418/1695906

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about programming. Please do not answer off-topic questions.